# не добавляются записи в базу данных

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Добавляю записи в бд таким образом:

```
public void addMovie(Movie movie){
    ContentValues contentValues = getContentValues(movie);
    mDatabase.insert(MOVIE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

где `getContentValues`

```
private static ContentValues getContentValues(Movie movie){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, movie.getId());
    values.put(TITLE, movie.getTitle());
    values.put(ORIGINAL_TITLE, movie.getOriginalTitle());
    values.put(ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE, movie.getOriginalLanguage());
    values.put(OVERVIEW, movie.getOverview());
    values.put(BACKDROP_PATH, movie.getBackdropPath());
    values.put(POSTER_PATH, movie.getPosterPath());
    values.put(RELEASE_DATE, movie.getReleaseDate());
    values.put(FIRST_AIR_DATE, movie.getFirstAirDate());
    values.put(LAST_AIR_DATE, movie.getLastAirDate());
    values.put(RUNTIME, movie.getRuntime());
    values.put(STATUS, movie.getStatus());
    values.put(NUMBER_OF_EPISODE, movie.getNumbersOfEpisodes());
    values.put(NUMBER_OF_SEASONS, movie.getNumberOfSeasons());
    values.put(BUDGET, movie.getBudget());
    values.put(REVENUE, movie.getRevenue());
    values.put(VOTE_AVERAGE, movie.getVoteAverage());
    values.put(VOTE_COUNT, movie.getVoteCount());
    values.put(POPULARITY, movie.getPopularity());
    return values;
}
```

Читаю данные с бд так:

```
   public List<Movie> getMovies(){
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

        MovieCursorWrapper cursor = queryMovies(null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "Record count " + cursor.getCount());

        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                movies.add(cursor.getMovie());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return movies;
    }
```

В результате получаю, что записи не добавляются.

**UPD:** Выяснилось что записи таки идут.Проблема с чтением.Курсор возвращает 0 записей.

**UPD 1** Метод `queryMovies`:

```
private MovieCursorWrapper queryMovies(String whereClause, String[] whereArg){
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
            MOVIE_TABLE_NAME,
                        null,
                        whereClause + "= ?",
                        whereArg,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
    );
    return new MovieCursorWrapper(cursor);
}
```

Метод используется в двух местах, в проверке - существует ли такой фильм или нет и в просто чтении без либо каких аргументов.

Comment: `queryMovies` - дайте код этого метода

Comment: Так получается же что у вас `where` выглядит как `where null = null`
Посмотрите какой запрос у вас получается в итоге. По идее такой:
`SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE null = null;` Такой запрос ничего не вернет.

Comment: @iksuy, как посмотреть выполняемый запрос?хотел "вытащить" бд и потестировать в SqliteBrowser ручками, но не вышло